# while read -r deletes second "\"

Tags: while-loop, aix, ifs

```
Here is my test file.

ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-APP-SDP-DAILY,D:\websites   ;D:\consoleapps   ;D:\Errorlogs   ;D:\Apache-Tomcat-7.0.19   ;C:\Inetpub\history   ;C:\windows\system32\msmq   ;C:\Inetpub\logs\logfiles   ;  ,05/17/2017,144.793,05/23/2017,0.116425
ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-APP-SDP-MONTHLY,D:\consoleapps   ;D:\websites   ;C:\Inetpub\history   ;C:\windows\system32\msmq   ;C:\Inetpub\logs\logfiles   ;D:\Errorlogs   ;D:\Apache-Tomcat-7.0.19   ;C:\Inetpub\history   ;C:\windows\system32\msmq   ;C:\Inetpub\logs\logfiles   ;  ,05/21/2017,145.171,No_Backup,0
ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-WIN-OS-MONTHLY,C:\   ;System State:\  ;  ,05/16/2017,31.6048,No_Backup,0
ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE15-GENERAL-ALL-WIN-OS-MONTHLY,C:\   ;System State:\  ;Shadow Copy Components:\ ;  ,05/20/2017,33.1401,No_Backup,0
```

And simply what I am doing is trying out this code below

```
echo "Client,Policy,Selection,Full_Backup_Date,Full_Size(GB),Incr_Backup_Date,Incr_Size(GB)" > /tmp/testfinal.csv
            while read -r valid
            do
                           active=`sudo /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/admincmd/bppllist $(echo $valid | awk -F "," '{print $2}') -l | grep "INFO" |awk '{print $12}'`

                           if [ "$active" -eq 0 ]
                           then
                                           echo $valid >> /tmp/test_final.csv
                           else
                                           full=`echo $valid | awk -F "," '{print $4}'`
                                           incr=`echo $valid | awk -F "," '{print $6}'`
                                           if [ "$full" != "No_Backup" ] && [ "$incr" != "No_Backup" ]
                                           then
                                                            echo $valid >> /tmp/testfinal.csv
                                           fi
                           fi
            done</tmp/test.csv
```

For some reason it deletes the second "\" and adds the next line

Here is the output.

```
ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-APP-SDP-DAILY,D:\websites ;D:ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-APP-SDP-MONTHLY,D:ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE13-CKENCOGTAPZP01-WIN-OS-MONTHLY,C:\ ;System State:\ ; ,05/16/2017,31.6048,No_Backup,0
ckencogtapzp01.corp.kencell.co.ke,KE15-GENERAL-ALL-WIN-OS-MONTHLY,C:\ ;System State:\ ;Shadow Copy Components:\ ; ,05/20/2017,33.1401,No_Backup,0
```

Any thoughts why, I have tried IFS='
' as it will ignore white space in test.csv but the result is same. I am head over toes on why it removes when it sees "\c" and adds the next line and then again deletes when it encounters "\c".

Any suggestions why?

Comment: It wasn't because of while,aix or IFS, it's because it encounters \c which in echo is "suppress further output", I have replaced it with printf which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `echo $valid` is to blame. Some versions of `echo` interpret backslash sequences. In particular, `\c` is used as a "suppress newline" escape.

`printf %s "$valid"` would be better.

Or, if you need the newline on the end that `echo` would normally add: `printf '%s\n%' "$valid"`

Comment: will printf "$valid\n" be equivalent to printf %s "$valid"

Comment: Not if `$valid` has any `%` in it

Comment: Yes, `echo` isn't standardized (or if is, it is not); the platform-independent format of `echo` is `printf`

Comment: printf %s prints all the lines together I need them to be separated, Also I see \Er is treated special and is been removed, is there any way where I can treat \ as text?

Comment: You might want to add line-breaks: `printf '%s\n' "$valid"`

Comment: It's still deleting any \ it encounters, i believe printf is also trying to interpret backslash as special character, is there any way I can treat it as plain text?

Comment: Actually bash does it, However one of my command in the script needs ksh which is "function $x $y $z | read p q", this doesn't work fine in bash.

Comment: I think this has drifted far enough from the original problem that it's a new question, which deserves to be posted separately, with no mention of `echo`. And trim the test case that down as far as you can while still demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't because of while,aix or IFS, it's because it encounters \c which in echo is "suppress further output", I have replaced it with printf which resolved the issue